# I need all Ethereum smart contracts

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

**The problem**

I would like to get all ERC20 token smart contract bytecodes in Ethereum network.

**The question**

Is there a way to scan the blockchain for ERC20 smart contracts and/or scan an address for a [ERC20] smart contract?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [EIP165](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-165.md). It allows you some form of introspection wether an address offers a certain interface. Obviously this only works for contracts that at least implement ERC20 and EIP165.

[How to detect if a contract implements ERC-165](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-165.md#how-to-detect-if-a-contract-implements-erc-165):

1. The source contact makes a STATICCALL to the destination address
   with input data:
   `0x01ffc9a701ffc9a700000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`
   and gas 30,000. This corresponds to
   `contract.supportsInterface(0x01ffc9a7)`.
2. If the call fails or return
   false, the destination contract does not implement ERC-165.
3. If the
   call returns true, a second call is made with input data
   `0x01ffc9a7ffffffff00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`.
4. If the second call fails or returns false, the destination contract
   does not implement ERC-165. Otherwise it implements ERC-165.

[How to detect if a contract implements any given interface](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-165.md#how-to-detect-if-a-contract-implements-any-given-interface):

1. If you are not sure if the contract implements ERC-165, use the
   above procedure to confirm.
2. If it does not implement ERC-165, then
   you will have to see what methods it uses the old-fashioned way.
3. If
   it implements ERC-165 then just call supportsInterface(interfaceID)
   to determine if it implements an interface you can use.

Comment: I'm confused by step 4.  If the second call `fails` or returns `true`, the destination contract does not implement ERC-165.   What will it respond with if it succeeds.